# Técnica de pruebas usada en Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Realicé algunas pruebas unitarias en Grails, he leido que las pruebas unitarias son pruebas de caja blanca.

En ese caso, ¿qué técnica es la que se usa en Grails para realizar estas pruebas, camino básico, condición, flujo de datos, bucles, u otra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No todas las pruebas unitarias son pruebas de caja blanca. Si acepta la definición de prueba unitaria sugerida por Kent Beck en su modelo de desarrollo guiado por pruebas, es evidente que estas pruebas son de caja negra (¿realiza sus pruebas unitarias antes de implementar el código que hacen que estas pruebas sean validas?), en caso contrario, si su objetivo es realizar estas pruebas unitarias luego de haber escrito este código, teniendo en cuenta detalles como el conjunto de entradas/salidas, relaciones de equivalencia entre un conjunto finito/infinito de datos, flujos o casos que deben probarse, en resumen, si se considera la estructura del código fuente esas pruebas unitarias son en efecto de caja blanca.

Dado lo anterior, si asume que son pruebas de caja blanca es evidente que cualquiera de las técnicas que usted menciona (más otras que encuentra en la literatura sobre calidad de software) son válidas; por el contrario, si considera que son pruebas de caja negra ninguna de las que usted mencionó son válidas, sino que debe asumir el contrato dado por la interfaz, las precondiciones y las salidas negociadas de acuerdo a la funcionalidad que su prueba unitaria esté probando. Suponga por ejemplo esta porción de código:

```
int multiply(int a, int b) {
    //Código aquí.
}
```

La interfaz del método recibe como parámetro dos números enteros y devuelve la multiplicación de estos. Una prueba unitaria de caja negra no considera la implementación que se haga en estos casos, depende puramente de la interfaz, las precondiciones y el contrato que estipule cómo debería funcionar este método, por lo tanto entre tantas pruebas unitarias de caja negra podríamos tener:

1. ¿Qué pasa si a y b son dos enteros negativos?
2. ¿Qué pasa si a y b son 0?
3. ¿Qué pasa si el resultado de multiplicar a y b desborda la capacidad de un entero?

entre otros.

```
void "debe retornar un numero positivo cuando ambos argumentos son negativos"() {
    expect:
    multiply(-3,-3) > 0
}

void "debe retornar cero cuando algun argumento es cero"() {
    expect:
    multiply(3,0) == 0
}
```

Ahora, supongamos que la implementación completa del método es:

```
int multiply(int a, int b) {
    if(b == 0) {
        return 0
    }
    if(b > 0 ) {
        return a + multiply(a, b - 1)
    }
    else {
        return -multiply(a, -b)
    }
}
```

(evidentemente la solución más obvia es retornar a*b) pero la forma en la que el código está diseñado invita a probar por varios casos: cuando b es igual a cero, cuando b es mayor a cero y cuando b es menor a cero, para lo cuál está haciendo uso de una de las varias técnicas disponibles: probar cada camino posible del flujo al menos una vez.

En conclusión, dependerá mucho de su código, si decide hacer pruebas de caja blanca elegir la técnica adecuada para realizar la implementación de sus pruebas unitarias. Aquí añado como salvedad que esta teoría es agnóstica al lenguaje de programación utilizado o al framework de pruebas que elija (es válido con [grails](/questions/tagged/grails) 3.1 y [junit](/questions/tagged/junit)/[spock](/questions/tagged/spock), o Java8 y [mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito), por ejemplo).

Comment: Quizás hacer pruebas de integración vendría bien también.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no sólo vienen bien, son absolutamente necesaria, pero el OP sólo pregunta por las unitarias.

Comment: @dwarandae muy clara tu respuesta, pensé que era algo como eso pero necesitaba argumentos, muchas gracias !!